# julia simplewebsockets - ERROR: ConnectError: HTTP.IOExtras.IOError

Tags: websocket, julia

see https://juliapackages.com/p/simplewebsockets  Basic usage client

```
using SimpleWebsockets

client = WebsocketClient()
ended = Condition()

listen(client, :connect) do ws
    listen(ws, :message) do message
        @info message
    end
    listen(ws, :close) do reason
        @warn "Websocket connection closed" reason...
        notify(ended)
    end
    for count = 1:10
        send(ws, "hello $count")
        sleep(1)
    end
    close(ws)
end
listen(client, :connectError) do err
    notify(ended, err, error = true)
end

@async open(client, "wss://socketsbay.com/wss/v2/1/demo/")
wait(ended)
```

Results in:
WARNING: both IOExtras and Base export "closewrite"; uses of it in module ConnectionPool must be qualified
ERROR: ConnectError: HTTP.IOExtras.IOError

Julia Version 1.9.3 (2023-08-24)

Been trying all day to make a simple websocket connection, trying different packages; WebSockets, WebsocketClient, DandelionWebSockets.
None of them successfully connected after trying many things.
Looking for something similar, easy as Python websocket-client, in Julia.
I am pretty new in Julia, a working websocket would make me stay in Julia.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Solved, why didn't it work earlier for me, why so hard to find such simple answer..

```
using HTTP
WebSockets.open("wss://websocketurl") do ws
   for msg in ws
      println(msg)
   end
end
```